# Capybara-webkit: not executing coffeescript properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, coffeescript, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have a button which when being clicked, it triggers an ajax post, and renders an alert.

It works great, but when running a test, the coffeescript doesn't get executed well.

## My files

**app/views/alerts/index.html.haml**

```
= link_to icon('plus', 'Show Alert'), new_alert_path, class: 'btn btn-with-icon btn-primary', remote: true
```

**app/controllers/alerts_controller.rb**

```
class AlertsController < BaseController
  def new
    @alert = Alert.new
  end
end
```

**app/views/alerts/new.js.coffee**

```
console.log "1" # => This is being executed
AlertComponent.show "show this message" # Here it breaks I think
console.log "2" # => It never arrives here
```

**app/assets/javascript/alert_component.js.coffee**

```
class AlertComponent
  @show: (description) ->
    console.log "3" # => This is not being executed
    # => Does some other stuff

end

window.AlertComponent = AlertComponent
```

## My test

```
click_link 'Show Alert' # => This is executed because I added a binging.pry in the controller and it arrives properly
wait_for_ajax
p page.driver.console_messages # => Below is what it returns
expect(page).to have_css '.alert-div'
```

## The result

The test fails, and the *page.driver.console_messages* returns this:

> {:line_number=>0, :message=>"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: AlertComponent", :source=>"undefined"}

As I already said, it works great on development and production. The problem is with the tests.

## My setup

I am using Capybara-webkit:

- capybara (2.9.2)
- capybara-webkit (1.1.0)

**spec/rails_helper.rb**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'

Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

# more stuff
```

Any ideas about why isn't this working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The big difference between development and test/production, when talking about the rails asset pipeline, is that in development each JS file is served separately, while in test/production they get concatenated together and served as one file.  This means that a JS error in one file doesn't stop the other files from being processed in development mode, but it can in test/production mode. It looks like it's probably aborting evaluation of the concatenated file before the AlertComponent class is created.

Check your browsers developer console when running the app in dev mode and fix any JS errors that are being logged.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, there is no js errors, and it works perfect in production mode.

Comment: @ArielScherman Then please add the fact it works in production to the question.  Anyway, the error is telling you that AlertComponent doesn't exist which means alert_component.js.coffee either isn't getting included by the asset pipeline or isn't getting processed when the file is loaded.  Assuming you have actually included the file (since it works in dev) this could be due to a JS error in some file (you say there are none), use of an ES6 method that capybara-webkit can't handle (it's based on an old Qt) or a misconfiguration in the rails asset pipeline.

Comment: The problem seemed to be, as you mentioned, the asset concatenation. I have turned the assets debug mode to false, and it showed me the error about the AlertComponent. However, it's weird that in production works fine. Do you know if I am doing something wrong regarding the component? I have a "require_tree ." in my application.js and the alertComponent file is the one I added above in the post description....

Comment: @ArielScherman no clue -- it could be that you have precompiled assets and have leftover files in public/assets which can stop the pipeline from finding changes, or it could just be that your test.rb is incorrect.  If you don't have manifest files left in your public/assets try creating a new app from scratch and see what the default test.rb settings and how they compare to yours.